# what is the difference between the default parameter in the __init__() method and the default in the body of the __Init__() method

Tags: python-3.x

what is the difference between the default parameters in the init method and the default parameters in the body of the intit method. Are they the same?

class Point(object):
    def **init**(self, x=0, y=0)

class Point(object):
    def **init**(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

Comment: Default arguments just change the value of the argument inside the function. Normally, you would bind `self.x = x` inside `__init__`, but you don't have to. The latter sets a value of `x` equal to 0 to the class instance, while the former sets a value of `x` equal to 0 inside the function scope.